# Mac上のPythonでturtleモジュールのインポートができない

Tags: python, macos, tkinter

Mac(El capitan)に標準インストールされているpython2.7.11で、

```
import turtle
```

がエラーになります。以前はインポートできていたのですが、エラーが出てしまいます。これを解決するため、アドバイスをいただけないでしょうか。2016年3月時点ではturtleモジュールをインポートして、動かすことはできていました。宜しくお願いします

以下が、シェルでの実行結果です

```
>>> import turtle     #インポート
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/turtle.py", line 107, in <module>
    import Tkinter as TK
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 39, in <module>
    import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ImportError: No module named _tkinter
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/usr/local/Cellar/`というのはHomebrewが使うディレクトリではないでしょうか。
そうだとすると、「Macに標準インストールされているpython2.7.11」ではなく、HomebrewでインストールしたPythonを使っているのではないでしょうか。
手元に環境がないので定かではないですが。

標準のPythonを使うか、HomebrewのPythonをTkに対応させるかすればよい筈です。

Comment: 確認したところ、Homebrewを使っていました。標準で使うPythonに変更したところ、まったく問題なくimportが出来ました。ご回答ありがとうございました。